# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'schedule'

Tags: python, linux, pip, schedule, modulenotfounderror

I have python program that imports schedule (`import schedule`) at the beginning. The code executes without a problem with python3 command, but starting it from other python file with `call("sudo python3 ProgramWithSchedule.py", shell=True)` returns error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'schedule'`. And I can't figure out why...

I have library schedule installed with pip, pip3 AND apt-get (tried all three just to be sure :)

Thanks!

Comment: That means the module was installed in a `venv`. And now you are in a different python `venv`. You have to re-install the module.

Comment: I have both files in the same folder, and schedule was also installed from the same folder, so how could I be in the different python venv now. And if so, how do I install it in that different venv?

Comment: Try installing it again. In your terminal enter **pip install schedule** if it is already installed, your output will be something like `package already installed` and if not your output will be like `package installed`

Comment: tried, output is `Requirement already satisfied`

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using a different **interpreter/virtual environment** for each project, which is generally considered the best practice.

You can apply the command below to create a file with all your installed modules, so you can use them whenever you want, by a single command to install all.

To keep/save all modules in a file:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

To install all of them with a single command in a new **interpreter/virtual environment**:

```
pip install requirements.txt
```

In case you tried installing a package and get an output:>>**Requirement already satisfied**.

You will find a **path** in your output where it says `Requirement already satisfied`, **copy the path**. Now go back to your working environment.

```py
import sys
sys.path.append("/the/path/you/copied")

import schedule
```

Comment: so how do I know to which venv do I install it? As far as I'm concerned, I have everything in the same venv/interpreter (see the comment up). Thanks!

Comment: You can also run in terminal `pip3 list | grep schedule`  and if it is installed you will have a version output, something like `schedule   0.6.0`

Comment: Yes I have a version output `schedule          1.1.0`, that's why this behavior is so weird to me. If you have any idea more why it doesn't work I would appreciate it, otherwise I will have to find a way how to do timed functions without this library...

Comment: Ok now what you can do is, in your output where it say's: ` Requirement already satisfied` you will see an **absolute path**, copy the path. Now go back to your python file, before **import schedule**. You should **import sys** and then `sys.path.append("the/path/you/copied")`

Comment: Whoaaa, it works! You are literally my lifesaver, I'm so happy right now. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: It was a pleasure @Matjaž Meža . I am glad it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to force the usage of the same python interpreter with :

```
call(f"sudo {os.getenv('PYTHON3')} ProgramWithSchedule.py", shell=True)
```

and call `your-script.py` with :

```
PYTHON3=$(type python3) your-script.py ...
```